# How to show base64String data as pdf in iframe or embed?

Tags: model-view-controller, iframe, base64, embed

This is for a hybrid application that runs in an Android mobile webview container but has MVC code behind. That's why I cannot use `window.open` to show pdf.

I need to use iframe or embed to show it on the MVC view.

I get data as bytes from a database.

```
byte[] RptData;
SqlReportData = reader.GetSqlBytes(0);
RptData = SqlReportData.Value;
return RptData;
```

then I convert it to Base64String and pass in viewModel.

```
 viewModel.PdfDataString = Convert.ToBase64String(pdfData);
```

I tried pretty many top suggestions I could find but none of them worked for me. E.g.:

[Iframe src set large base64 data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766667/iframe-src-set-large-base64-data)

[how to display base64 encoded pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674532/how-to-display-base64-encoded-pdf)

[Display ASP.NET generated pdf byte[] to web page without saving the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108278/display-asp-net-generated-pdf-byte-to-web-page-without-saving-the-file/17562800#17562800)

```
<div><iframe src="" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
</div>
       
<div>
  <embed src="" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf"/>
</div>

<script>
    var pdfData = '@Model.PdfDataString';
    $("iframe").attr("src", 'data:application/pdf;base64,{0}'.replace('{0}', pdfData));
    $("embed").attr("src", 'data:application/pdf;base64,{0}'.replace('{0}', pdfData));
</script>
```

I want to show this Base64String data as a pdf on a MVC view.
I am trying with iframe and embed both.
iframe shows blank and embed is not displaying.

Chrome debugger shows:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcKCjQgMCB....(ShowMore 1.6MB)

Comment: I was able to achieve this using pdf.js library. pretty cool.  - https://www.sitepoint.com/custom-pdf-rendering/