# Adobe PDF Reader Plugin in TWEBBROWSER on new PC

Tags: delphi, pdf, twebbrowser

according to [PDF in TWEbbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62174142/delphi-display-a-pdf-in-a-twebbrowser) I tried to run an selfprogrammed Delphi Prg which displays the PDF in a TWEBBROWSER component fine. But on 2 new PCs, where I just installed the Adobe DC PDF Reader I only see a gray window - no PDF anymore. How to fix this? I can see the PDF in IE. I Have Delphi Berlin.
Thanks for help

Comment: What are the differences between the PC where it works and the others?

Comment: *"I can see the PDF in IE"* Are you sure you tested with IE and not Edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why PFD isn't correctly shown in TWebBrowser is the fact that by default TWebBrowser is opening web pages in Compatibility mode. This means that the web pages are opened in Interent Explorer 7 mode wihtout any extensions. And in order for you to be able to open PDF in Internet explorer it is done so in Acrobar Reader Web Extension.

In order to make TWebBrowser open web pages in compatibility mode for newest IE version you need to [Opt in to the browser emulation feature using the documented registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25843958/3636228)

NOTE: You need to opt in to the browser emulation on every computer where your program is used.
Or you could switch to the use of TEdgeBrowser instead as Robson Benedito suggested in his answer.

Comment: THANKS a lot- I do not have Sydney RAD only Berlin. So this is my solution .

Answer (score 1):

TWebBrowser component, when in Windows, navigates using the old Internet Explorer (not Microsoft Edge).

To ensure that it works you should open Microsoft Internet explorer and try to open this document in the machine that is showing the problem.

If it doesn't open you should fix it inside IE before open in you Delphi app. If it does, it could be an incompatibility with this Adobe plugin and the engine provided/used by TWebBrowser. In this case you can switch to TEdgeBrowser component that provides you the ability to have you own browser (with Chromnium) even if the Microsoft Edge is not installed (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_TEdgeBrowser_Component_and_Changes_to_the_TWebBrowser_Component).

With TEdgeBrowser you can open PDF directly without using plugin (even those installed in Windows).

Using TWebBrowser can also lead you to others problems with others PCs depending on the Internet Explorer (like proxy/javascript/plugins/etc).

Comment: Thanks unfortunately TEdgeBrowser is only in Sydney and not in BERLIN 10.1 I am using.